# DataGrid / Infinispan pair update while making initial loading

Tags: infinispan, in-memory-database

A JBoss Datagrid / Infinispan cache is fed by an huge database through JDBC. 
So it will take quite a long to make the initial fill.

In the while the Database can be modified by other components.

What happens in case the database trigger sends a record update to DataGrid in these two situation:

1. The key-value pair is already load in the cache?
2. The key-value pair is not yet load in the cache?

And in case a new ercord is created and one is deleted?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the configuration with JDBC **cache store**, there's no synchronization DB -> DataGrid. DataGrid expects that it's the only user of DB (or rather the involved table), and it reads or writes it when it needs. There are no triggers used by the DataGrid.